Find a propper permutation under given contraint(s)

Let $ a,m,C\in \mathbb{R}^n $ given with
$$ a:=\begin{pmatrix}a_1\\\vdots\\a_n\end{pmatrix}\quad m:=\begin{pmatrix}m_1\\\vdots\\m_n\end{pmatrix}\quad C:=\begin{pmatrix}c\\\vdots\\c\end{pmatrix} $$
such that $ a_1\leq a_2 \leq ...\leq a_n $ and $ 0\leq m_k $ for all $ k=1,...,n $.
Further let $ \varepsilon>0 $ be fixed.
Find a permutation $$ \pi:\{1,...,n\}\to \{1,...,n\} $$
such that the unequation
$$ -\varepsilon \leq \sum_{k=1}^n (a_k-c)\cdot m_{\pi(k)}\leq\varepsilon \quad (*)$$
is being satisfied with the constraint $$ \min\{m_{\pi(1)}, m_{\pi(2)}\} \geq m_{\pi(n)} \quad \Longleftrightarrow \quad m_{\pi(1)}\ \geq m_{\pi(n)} \land m_{\pi(2)}\ \geq m_{\pi(n)}. $$

The most naive way would be indeed to try out all $ n! $ possible permutation's which is quite inefficient for already small values for $n$ like $ n=10 $ and larger.
Beside this naive way I was thinking about a way without considering the constraint at first:
Starting with taking a permutation
$$ \pi:\{1,...,n\}\to \{1,...,n\} $$
such that $$ m_{\pi(1)}\ \leq m_{\pi(2)} \leq...\leq m_{\pi(n)} $$
which means I sort all values (components) of my vector $ m $ from small to big.
Now I just calculate the sum with my first picked permuation and see if the unequation in $(*)$ holds. If so then I'm already done. That was the boring part.
Now there are two cases:
1.) The sum in $(*)$ exeeds the upper bound $ \varepsilon $. I swap appropriately two values (taking a new permuation) and I calculate with that the sum expression in $(*)$ again and I check it again.
2.) The sum in $(*)$ falls below the lower bound $ - \varepsilon $. I swap appropriately two values (taking a new permuation) and I calculate with that the sum expression in $(*)$ again and I check it again.
You could wrap these two cases into a while-loop and stay there until the condition in $(*)$ is being satisfied.
I calculated with this method a few examples and it seemed to work like

$$ a:=\begin{pmatrix}-20\\-11\\-2\\8\\15\\23\end{pmatrix},\quad 
m:=\begin{pmatrix}100\\90\\90\\700\\100\\700\end{pmatrix},\quad 
C:=\begin{pmatrix}9\\9\\9\\9\\9\\9\end{pmatrix} $$
with $ \varepsilon=2000 $
Calculation:
Sort the components of $ m $ leeds to $ (90,90,100,100,700,700) $ with the result of $8390$ which exeeds $ \varepsilon=2000 $.
Further swaps are underlined:
$ (\underline{90},90,\underline{100},100,700,700) \to (100,90,90,100,700,700)$ with the result of $8210$ which exeeds $ \varepsilon=2000 $.
$ (100,\underline{90},90,\underline{100},700,700) \to (100,100,90,90,700,700)$ with the result of $8020$ which exeeds $ \varepsilon=2000 $.
$ (100,100,\underline{90},90,\underline{700},700) \to (100,100,700,90,90,700)$ with the result of $-2350$ which falls below $ - \varepsilon=-2000 $.
$ (\underline{100},100,700,\underline{90},90,700) \to (90,100,700,100,90,700)$ with the result of $-2070$ which falls below $ - \varepsilon=-2000 $.
$ (90,\underline{100},700,100,\underline{90},700) \to (90,90,700,100,100,700)$ with the result of $-1810$ which is greater than $ - \varepsilon=-2000 $.
So $ (90,90,700,100,100,700) $ is a propper order of components of $ m $ to satisfy $(*)$ but not the constrain yet.

Is there a better way (considering the constraints too) to solve my problem than my way I have illustrated in the upper example?

The problem is NP-hard, even without the constraint.  In particular, it is at least as hard as the equal-cardinality partition problem, which is NP-hard: specifically, consider the special case where $m$ contains $n/2$ copies of $+1$ and $n/2$ copies of $-1$.  So I don't think you should expect any efficient algorithm.
You could try using an off-the-shelf integer linear programming solver.  It is easy to set up integer linear constraints to require $m'$ to be a permutation of $m$, and then the requirement that $-\epsilon \le (a-c) \cdot m' \le \epsilon$ amounts to two linear inequalities.

But what kind of linear programming solver are appropriate? Because the components of the vector $m'$ are already given. So I need a propper permutation of the components of $m$. Like for example CPLEX would consider $ m' $ as a vector which is calculated which means it doesen't consider the fact that the compoents are already given and just need to be permuted appriate.

@hallo007, Integer linear programming, not linear programming.  I understand.  As I said, it is not hard to write linear constraints to require $m'$ to be a permutation of $m$.  If you're not sure how to do that, I suggest doing a little bit of studying on formulating problems as ILP.  CPLEX is an excellent solver if you have that.  There are other solvers as well if you don't have access to CPLEX.

CPLEX seems to be not able to have the option to build in a constraint that the searched vector $m'$ is a permutation of $m$.

@hallo007, No, that can be expressed using a number of linear inequalities and additional variables.  I suggest reading a bit about how to formulate problems using integer linear programming.  See, e.g., http://faculty.nps.edu/dell/docs/Formulettes060425.pdf.  Give it a try, and if you get stuck, try asking a new question where you ask how to express the constraint that the vector $m'$ is a permutation of the vector $m$ using integer linear programming, either here or on Operations Research or Computer Science.

I watched some YouTube videos where some examples about ILP were given but there I couldn't see any similar example how formulate such a problem with permutations.

@hallo007, I'm going to refer you back to the advice that I've already given.  I suggest following the advice I gave above.
